# AutoPostBack using ASP.NET text box and AjaxControlToolkit CalendarExtender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would like to like to trigger a postback after user selects a date. Am using the AjaxControlToolkit's CalendarExtender control. The date textbox which is associated to the extender is editable too which enables the user to manually enter the date in a particular format. Values of quite a few controls which reside on that page are to be updated depending on the newly selected date and hence going to the server is a must.
  I did try using the OnClientDateSelectionChanged property of the extender which lets me hook in my custom javascript, using which i was planning to trigger a postback but for some odd reason the function gets called only if the date is selected using an extender and not when manually edited (Hoping that it doesn't catch the click event over textbox's change).

Am sure many have tackled this issue before. Please do share. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is, Keep It Simple as they say. Set AutoPostBack of the text box to true and capture the OnTextChanged event on the server side.